# EkEventStore Duplicate events

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ekevent

I m working iOS calendar events in my app.

I dont want to add duplicate event i.e if event is not modified i dont want to add it.

I m using saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error method from EkEventStore. As per documentation, this method returns NO if event is already in store.

But m getting duplicate events also in Calendar. Please suggest me something if m doing wrong anything.

Thanks.